# QML Slot not displaying double value from serial input

Tags: qt, arduino, qml, registering

I'm struggling to get my serial input "analogread2" converted to a double, to display in QML.

Ive added the Q_property, the root context in the main.cpp, and I can add the property in the qml, but I cant get it to display in text format.

```
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
SerialPort serialport;
//engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("serialport", &serialport);
qmlRegisterType<SerialPort>("SerialPortlib", 1, 0, "SerialPort");
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")))
```

header.

```
Q_PROPERTY(double newValue MEMBER m_oil_pressure_volt WRITE set_oil_pressure_volt NOTIFY oil_pressure_volt_Changed )
```

qml

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    id: gauge

    SerialPort{
        // what would I put in here to display the text value (double)
    }
}
```

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Show me the SerialPort class

Comment: try with `OnOil_pressure_volt_Changed{console.log(newValue);}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do the test I am assuming that you are sending the data from the arduino in one of the following ways:

```
Serial.println(data);
Serial.print(data);
```

Assuming the above has been implemented the serialport class, this has a function called openDefault that scans the devices that are connected through serial and searches for the word "Arduino" within description or manufacturer and if one finds it connects to it.

The complete code can be found at: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/Arduino-QML

**serialport.h**

```
#ifndef SERIALPORT_H
#define SERIALPORT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QSerialPort>
#include <QSerialPortInfo>

class SerialPort : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(double oil_pressure_volt READ get_oil_pressure_volt WRITE set_oil_pressure_volt NOTIFY oil_pressure_volt_Changed )

public:
    SerialPort(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~SerialPort();

    double get_oil_pressure_volt() const;
    void set_oil_pressure_volt(double newValue);

public slots:
    void onReadData();

signals:
    void oil_pressure_volt_Changed(double newValue);

private:
    QSerialPort *arduino;

    double mOil_pressure_volt;

    QSerialPortInfo portInfo;

    void openDefault();
};
```

**serialport.cpp**

```
#include "serialport.h"

#include <QDebug>

SerialPort::SerialPort(QObject *parent):QObject(parent)
{

    arduino = new QSerialPort(this);
    connect(arduino, &QSerialPort::readyRead, this, &SerialPort::onReadData);
    openDefault();
}

SerialPort::~SerialPort()
{
    delete arduino;
}

void SerialPort::set_oil_pressure_volt(double newValue)
{
    if (mOil_pressure_volt == newValue)
        return;

    mOil_pressure_volt = newValue;
    emit oil_pressure_volt_Changed(mOil_pressure_volt);
}

void SerialPort::onReadData()
{
    if(arduino->bytesAvailable()>0){

        QByteArray data = arduino->readAll();

        QString value = QString(data).trimmed();
        qDebug()<< value;
        bool ok;
        double val = value.toDouble(&ok);
        if(ok)
            set_oil_pressure_volt(val);
    }
}

void SerialPort::openDefault()
{
    for(auto info: QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()){
        qDebug()<<info.portName()<<info.description()<<info.manufacturer();
        if(!info.isBusy() && (info.description().contains("Arduino") || info.manufacturer().contains("Arduino"))){
            portInfo = info;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(portInfo.isNull()){
        return;
    }

    arduino->setPortName(portInfo.portName());
    arduino->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud115200);
    arduino->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    arduino->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    arduino->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    arduino->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

    if(arduino->open(QSerialPort::ReadWrite))
        qDebug()<<"Connected to "<< portInfo.manufacturer()<< " on " << portInfo.portName();
    else
        qCritical()<<"Serial Port error: " << arduino->errorString();

}

double SerialPort::get_oil_pressure_volt() const
{
    return mOil_pressure_volt;
}
```

Example:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include "serialport.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    qmlRegisterType<SerialPort>("SerialPortLib", 1, 0, "SerialPort");


    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;
    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import SerialPortLib 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Test")

    SerialPort{
        onOil_pressure_voltChanged: {
            tx.text = "%1".arg(oil_pressure_volt);
        }
    }

    Text {
        id: tx
        anchors.fill: parent
        font.family: "Helvetica"
        font.pointSize: 20
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that help, I'm using; serial.println(analogRead2); id also like to read analogRead3, 4, 5, 6 etc. Would I be able to change the onReadData property to SLOT?

Comment: I worked it out, and we now have two readings that I can multiply to give a voltage and pressure. Is there a better way or a more improved way of buffering and parsing the data, I'm loosing some chunks of data. Much appreciated.

Comment: You could store it in a queue, and then process it in another thread. If my answer helps you mark it as correct please.

Comment: Yeah certainly mate, can I ask for one more bit of help, id like to use this value now obtained in a rotaty gauge, ive defined my start and stop angles, so would I just use the same theory to get the value to work for this.  '  currentValue: SerialPort.arg(oil_pressure_volt) * (maxValue - minValue) + minValue;'

Comment: Hi Guys, Ive been using this code for a long time and learning lots from it so thank you again. Ive just updated qt to 4.5 and whe running this bae code i dont get an output... could you help my in adding some debugging to the code so i can see that qt is recieving the serial informtion, try and narro down the problem.

Comment: Qt 4.5? The current version of Qt is 5.10. Also you have not marked my answer as correct, you must press the arrow that is on the left side of my question

Comment: I apologise, i thought i had already done that in my profile... Yes the qtcreator version is 4.5, could you help me add a debug line so i can see if the code is recieving the serial input? Im trying to simply fault find.

Comment: Qt Creator is an editor, should not cause you any problem, what version of Qt do you have? QtCreator is different from Qt.

Comment: Im running qt5.10 on windows 10. in debug mode im getting an error now also:- onecore\com\combase\inc\comcataloghelpers.hpp(67)\combase.dll!756B8550: (caller: 756B82E0) ReturnHr(1) tid(d8) 80004002 No such interface supported

Comment: Check if you have installed all the packages, it seems that it is a bug, report it to Qt. It is not a problem with the code.

Comment: I didnt think it was a problem with the code as ive had it working perfectly for around 6 months, do you think if i revert to a previous version it should work fine?

Comment: probably, I can not tell you anything

Comment: I managed to find the source of the problem after a lot of installing deleting and checking and it turned out to be the naming of the device in the description and the manufacturer. I removed the arduino and perfect.

Comment: Would I be able to ask another question inthis thread or would you want me to start a new question... It relates to adding some code so I can send a signal out to a digital pin on the arduino, i.e. digital pin 3 high, or digital pin 3 low.

Comment: @StephenThomasGardiner No, you must create a new question.